# Switch to desktop with logo button - Win 8.1

Tags: shortcuts, desktop

For example: I'm running a program in fullscreen or I'm in Metro mode, and I want to switch back to the desktop.

I know the shortcut Logo+D, but that minimizes all the windows when switching to desktop.

Does anybody know a way to switch to the desktop with all the windows as they were?

Comment: This is a bit counter-intuitive.  The desktop is essentially a maximised window.  As this runs at the bottom of the Z Order you will never be able to 'get to it' without minimising other windows.  In short no.  There is no way to do this.  Put another way, before pressing Logo+D the desktop is there with all the windows 'as they were'.

Comment: For example: When I'm running a program in fullscreen, or when I'm in the Metro view, I'd like to switch to the desktop with all the windows as I left them. (Consider it's Win 8.1)

Comment: I understand what you mean now.  I do not know of a mechanism and sadly do not think it is possible. Hopefully someone else will.  Maybe edit the question to indicate the desire to switch from Metro to Classic Desktop without disturbing the Order of the windows.